# website uploads on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

I have a C# ASP.Net website I'm trying to develop. It currently has and upload for pdf files and images, the details of which are stored in a database. The porblem is when I refresh the page it uploads the image or pdf again, and will keep uploading every time I refresh. How can I prevent this from happening? My C# code is quite basic so here it is. However it doesn't work... When I check the database there are duplicate entries. This method should only fire on button click but it fires when the page is refreshed also. And this method is not in the page load either. Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
public void Upload_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String filename = txtFileName.Text;
    if(filename != "")//checks if there is something to upload if(true) then upload
    {
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO tblFileNames (filename) VALUES ('"+filename+"')";
        new DBHelper().runSQL(SQL);
    }
    txtFileName.Text = ""; //resets the value in txtFileName so it won't run the if
}
```

Comment: Your code is (potentially) susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - I'd suggest you fix that _fast_.

Comment: Ah... yes it appears that it is, thanks for pointing that out. Can you point me to a place that will help me get that fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a normal redirect after the file is uploaded, then you won't have to worry about the re-upload of the file.

`Response.Redirect("~/path/to/your/file.aspx");`

Answer (score 1):

It happened because the page maintained its ViewState.

To prevent it from happening, try to set EnableViewState="false" on your page and you may add Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx", true) in your public void Upload_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) method.